# How can I get a list of git branches, ordered by most recent merge and commit?

Tags: git, shell

I need to get list of branches, ordered by most recent activity (merge or commit).
I am using this command:

```
git for-each-ref --sort='-committerdate' --format='%(refname)%09%(committerdate)' refs/remotes | sed -e 's-refs/remotes/--'
```

and get this

origin/part_3 Tue Aug 30 17:45:58 2016 +0300
origin/part_2 Tue Aug 30 17:45:58 2016 +0300

But, actually I was made commit to branch 'part_3', then merge it into 'part_2' from 'part_3', and I whant to get this:

**origin/part_2 Tue Aug 30 17:45:58 2016 +0300**
origin/part_3 Tue Aug 30 17:45:58 2016 +0300

How can I sort it by merge\commit?

Comment: After the merge, they both point to same commit, so you get the same date. You need to sort on the `reflog` date: `git reflog --date=local part_2` and `git reflog --date=local part_3` to see the your _action_ time.

Answer (score 0):

I always use `git branch -av`. `-a` to see all branches including remotes and `v`for verbose (hash, commit message, ...).

Here, you don't see the history, but I think that is not what you are looking for.